# Unity: Difference between Lock View to Selected and Frame Selected?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have been testing the <kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> which is "Lock view to selected" and "Frame Selected" - but I can't seem to figure out the difference.

They both do exactly the same, they zoom in close to the object in the Scene.

I am of course not fully understanding the difference because there are 2 different commands so they must be there for a reason.

Can anyone help with understanding when i would use one of the other and pointing out how I can notice the difference ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Lock view to selected` additionally **keeps** the SceneView **locked** on according object even if it is **moving** during PlayMode. This is extremly useful for keeping track of moving objects like for example rigidbodies.

Here is the result after using <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. As you can see the SceneView follows the locked object.

[image]

Instead using only <kbd>F</kbd> focuses the SceneView on the object **once** but does not keep it focused as you can see below

[image]

---

Another small difference is that <kbd>F</kbd> only works while the mouse is over the SceneView while <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> works always as soon as something is selected in the hierarchy.